# Read visualforce as pdf in the attachment and display it in record page (attachment is blank)

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components, attachment

I'm creating a visuaforce page as pdf to display some account and opportunity fields in pdf. But when I try to read the pdf and add it into attachement I find that is blank. Please could you help me to find a solution or to create pdf in js because I'm working with lwc. After reading the pdf in apex method I call it in js.

apex method

```
PageReference page = new PageReference('/apex/PDFContract');
// add our record id
page.getParameters().put('Id', recordId);
System.debug('Before AccountPDFController::::::::::::::::::::');
AccountPDFController a=new AccountPDFController(tempId,OppId);
Attachment att=new Attachment();
att.Body=page.getContentAsPDF();
System.debug('getContentAsPDF:::::'+page.getContentAsPDF());
att.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
system.debug('att.Body***************'+att.Body);
att.Name='Contract2 ' + System.now().format('yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss')+'.pdf';
system.debug('Contract***************'+att.Name);

att.parentId=recordId;
insert att;
```

visualforce page

```
 <apex:page controller="PDFController" renderAs="pdf">
    <h1>The Contract</h1>
      <apex:pageblock mode="detail" title="Account Fields">
        <apex:pageblocktable cellpadding="3"  rules="rows"
          value="{!accFields.accountsLabels}" var="pr" 
              headerclass="eventTable" footerclass="eventTable"
           styleclass="eventTable">
     <apex:repeat value="{!pr}" var="key">
     <apex:column >
     <apex:outputText value="{!pr[key]+': ' }"/>
     <apex:outputText value="{!accFields.accountsValues[0][key]}"/>
     <!-- you can add more fields -->
     </apex:column>
     </apex:repeat>
     </apex:pageblocktable>
     </apex:pageblock>
     <apex:pageblock mode="detail" title="Opportunity Fields">
     <apex:pageblocktable cellpadding="3"  rules="rows"
      value="{!oppFields.opportunitiesLabels}" var="pr" 
      headerclass="eventTable" footerclass="eventTable"
      styleclass="eventTable">
     <apex:repeat value="{!pr}" var="key">
     <apex:column >
     <apex:outputText value="{!pr[key]+': ' }"/>
     <apex:outputText value="{!oppFields.opportunitiesValues[0][key]}"/>
     <!-- you can add more fields -->
     </apex:column>
   </apex:repeat>
 </apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageblock>
```

Comment: you should share the code, not the image!

Comment: Do you want to display the pdf generated in the lightning environment, not a classic environment?

Comment: Hey  @Klecool . I want to add the pdf as attachment in lightning environment.

Comment: In the debug log are you seeing results for getContentAsPDF ?